# julia: rerun unittests upon changes to files

Tags: unit-testing, julia

Are there julia libraries that can run unittests automatically when I make changes to the code?

In Python there is the `pytest.xdist` library which can run unittests again when you make changes to the code. Does julia have a similar library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution could be made using the standard library module [FileWatching](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/FileWatching/index.html); specifically [`FileWatching.watch_file`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/FileWatching/index.html#FileWatching.watch_file).  Despite the name, it can be used with directories as well.  When something happens to the directory (e.g., you save a new version of a file in it), it returns an object with a field, `changed`, which is `true` if the directory has changed.  You could of course combine this with [Glob](https://github.com/vtjnash/Glob.jl) to instead watch a set of source files.

You could have a separate Julia process running, with the project's environment active, and use something like:

```
julia> import Pkg; import FileWatching: watch_file

julia> while true
           event = watch_file("src")
           if event.changed
               try
                   Pkg.pkg"test"
               catch err
                   @warn("Error during testing:\n$err")
               end
           end
       end
```

More sophisticated implementations are possible; with the above you would need to interrupt the loop with Ctrl-C to break out.  But this does work for me and happily reruns tests whenever I save a file.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a Github repository, there are ways to set up Travis or Appveyor to do this. This is the testing method used by many of the registered modules for Julia. You will need to write the unit test suite (with `using Test`) and place it in a /test subdirectory on the github repository. You can search for julia and those web services for details.

Comment: That is a helpful answer.

Comment: But it should ideally be run again and again whenever I make changes to the code locally, during development, every time I save the code :) Still, upvote :)

Comment: Visual Studio Code has a Test Explorer feature that should be extensible to Julia but is not yet incorporated into the Julia features of VS Code. I may ask on discourse about this.

Answer (score 1):

Use a standard GNU Makefile and call it from various places depending on your use-case

- Your .juliarc if you want to check for tests on startup.
- Cron if you want them checked regularly
- Inside your module's **init** function to check every time a module is loaded.

Since GNU makefiles detect changes automatically, calls to make will be silently ignored in the absence of changes.